# How to indicate articulation on only one volte of a repeat?

Tags: sheet-music, repeats, articulation

A source I’m transcribing has a piece of music repeated, with an articulation applied only once. E.g.,

> A B C D | A B E F | G F E D | A B C D | A B E> F |

or, using Lilypond notation,

```
\fixed c' {
  a, b, c d
  a, b, e f
  g f e d
  a, b, c d
  a, b, e\> f
}
```

I’m rewriting this as

> A B ¹⁽C D⁾  ²⁽E F⁾  <sub>*Fine.*</sub>
> G F E D | <sub>*D.C. al Fine*</sub>

or

```
\fixed c' {
  \repeat segno 2 {
    \repeat volta 2 {
      a, b,
      \alternative {
        { c d }
        { e f }
      }
    }
    \volta 2 \fine
    \volta 1 {
      g f e d
    }
  }
}
```

But how can I annotate that final E to indicate
“the very last time you play this, play it staccato”?

Something like,

> (4ᵗʰ× >)
> perhaps?

(This is not a question of how to achieve that notation in Lilypond,
but rather what the resulting sheet music should look like.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the articulation in square brackets with a note ‘staccato 2nd X only’.   If it gets messy or cluttered, write it out.

Comment: Footnote? above-staff text note?

Comment: Not a footnote.  Right by the actual note.   This can't be 'tidied away'.  It's an unusual requirement that needs to be prominent.

Comment: Is https://imgur.com/a/co69KeP what you describe?  (Lilypond makes parentheses easier than square brackets; if the choice is critical, please say so.)

Comment: @J.C.Salomon Well, sort of!  The text mentions staccato, but the articulation in parentheses  is an accent.    And, in this case, couldn't the job have been done with less fuss by having longer 1x and 2x endings?

Answer (score 0):

There is no notation standard for notating "do this on the nth time" style instructions. So if you actually find space for it (such things can lead to clutter) you can go for anything like "last time staccato" or "4x staccato", or anything.

Alternatively you could do something like this:

```
\fixed c' {
  \repeat segno 2 {
    \repeat volta 4 {
      a, b,
      \alternative {
        \volta #'(1 3) { c d }
        \volta 2 { e f }
        \volta 4 { e-. f }
      }
    }
    \volta 2 \fine
    \volta 1 {
      g f e d
    }
  }
}
```